# Problem with getting monospace in Ace editor in React (using material ui framework)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, ace-editor

I need to integrate a code editor in my React website. I found the ACE editor as an npm package which was easy to install and use. But somehow I am not able to get Monospace fonts to work with it. I tried to add inline style with fontFamily but the visible text was still in default font of Material UI, which is the framework I use. **I see phantom white text blocks in monospace with the spacing of cursor and while selecting text.** I am able to use Monospace font with Typography component of Material ui easily, but it is not working with this Editor Component. Please give any possible ideas.

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-python";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AceEditor
                    mode="python"
                    theme="github"
                    onChange={code=>console.log(code)}
                    fontSize={20}
                    showPrintMargin={true}
                    //style={{fontFamily:"Monospace"}}
                    showGutter={true}
                    highlightActiveLine={true}
                    value={`print("Hello")`}
                    setOptions={{
                    //  fontFamily:"Monospace",
                        enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
                        enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
                        enableSnippets: false,
                        showLineNumbers: true,
                        tabSize: 4
                    }}
                />
                <Typography >
                    <Box fontFamily="Monospace">
                        Monospace font visible
                    </Box>
                </Typography>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

If you have any other suggestions for easy implementation of code editor, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I've tried to recreate this issue in CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-thompson-wf9zf?file=/src/App.js. It looks fine - the only difference is on the `font-size` & `font-weight` - which on `AceEditor` is defined to be `20px` & `bold` (for keywords) respectively. Other than that, `monospace` font is working. If the issue persists, fork my SandBox and recreate your issue.

Comment: Thanks man, I had lost all hope after trying a lot of things, after seeing your effort I went back and tried to isolate the problem, and it worked! I was using BrowserRouter in App.js for different pages, and one of the pages I was importing within it had a weird css file associated with it, which I had copied from some documentation. Fixing it fixed the issue. Thank you for your time.